# Compiling with FFMPEG using g++

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, cygwin, gnu

Im trying to compile a github code that requires opencv and FFMPEG. The code is:
https://github.com/prouast/heartbeat
This is what i have

```
g++ -std=c++11 -LC:\Users\Anon\Desktop\ffmpeg-20171225-613f789-win32-shared\bin -LC:\Anaconda\pkgs\opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0\Library\lib -LC:\MinGW\var\lib\mingw-get\data -IC:\Anaconda\envs\mywindowscv\Library\include -lopencv_core310 -lopencv_highgui310 -lopencv_imgcodecs310 -lopencv_imgproc310 -lopencv_objdetect310 -lopencv_video310 -lopencv_videoio310 -lavcodec-58 -lavformat-58 -lavutil-56 -lswscale-5 -lmingw32-libarchive -lSDLMain -mwindows Heartbeat.cpp FFmpegDecoder.cpp FFmpegEncoder.cpp opencv.cpp RPPG.cpp Baseline.cpp -o Heartbeat
```

I get the following error:

```
    In file included from Heartbeat.cpp:16:0:
FFmpegDecoder.hpp:16:36: fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory

                                    ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from FFmpegDecoder.cpp:9:0:
FFmpegDecoder.hpp:16:36: fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory

                                    ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from FFmpegEncoder.cpp:9:0:
FFmpegEncoder.hpp:17:32: fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
```

what to do?

Comment: You're linking the `avcodec` library (`-lavcodec-58`), but not pointing to the compiler to where its headers are stored (need a `-I<avcodec include path>`). The compiler then can't find the header file `avcodec.h`.

Comment: there is no avcodec.h after installing ffmpeg on windows. Should i rewrite the original code to include library instead? should i enable static libraries? how to enable?

Comment: No, you should just install the FFmpeg development header files that belong to the libraries that you installed.

Comment: just realised i needed the developers version of ffmpeg. thanks